# to sort the word based on the number characters that contains in java

Tags: java, string, sorting

How sort the word based on the number characters that contains in java??
e.g.

```
String Given : "my name is dhana"
O/p should be : "dhana name my is"
```

Comment: have you tried googling on the topic "sort java string by length"?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: OK,go ahead.Come back if you stuck some  where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an alternative that does not require to create a custom `Comparator`.  I'm proposing it only for the sake of completeness.

1. Split the String in words.
2. Create a SortedMap.
3. Iterate on the word list.
4. Populate it with "%03d%05d".format(999-aWord.length(),i) -> aWord , where i is the index of aWord in in the word list.  Here, the key is of the form *xxxyyyyy*, where *xxx* is an inverse of word length (998 for l=1, 997 for l=2, etc), so sorting if from longest to shortest, and *yyyyy* allows to differentiate words of the same length (as well as multiple occurrences of the same word).
5. Result is theMap.values().

```
String input= "This is a string with differently sized words. This is another sentence." ;
String[] splitInput= input.split("[ .]") ;
TreeMap<String,String> theMap= new TreeMap<String,String>() ;
int index= 0 ;
for(String word: splitInput ) {
    if( word.length() > 0 ) {
        String key= String.format("%03d%05d",(999-word.length()),index) ;
        theMap.put(key,word);
        index++;
    }
}
System.out.println(theMap.values());
```

Produces output:

```
[differently, sentence, another, string, sized, words, This, with, This, is, is, a]
```

, which is correct.  In fact, `String`s of the same size are listed by position in `input`.

Answer (score 2):

- take a `string`
- `split` it by space (into words)
- convert `array` into `ArrayList`
- create custom `comparator` to `sort` the way you want (here by `length`)

Comment: downvote here ? interesting...

Comment: No need to convert it into a list, arrays can be easily sorted too...

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
  public void func()
        {
        String input =  "my name is dhana";
        String input_array[] = input.split(" ");
        Collections.sort(input_array, new CustomComparator());
        print_Array(input_array);
       }
```

**CustomComaparator.java**

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>
   {
      public int compare(String a, String b) {  
      if (a.length() > b.length()) {
         return -1;
      } else if (a.length() < b.length()) {
         return 1;
      }
      return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `CustomComparator` coded like this will sort the List in an ascending order instead of a descending one.

Comment: thanks for notifying me :) i changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which compares by length first and if the lengths are the same, use the `String.compareTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem can be this using regex on split:

```
    String str = "my name is dhana";
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+"));

    print(items);

    Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String s0, String s1) {
                            // Descending order
                if (s0.length() < s1.length())
                    return 1;
                else if (s0.length() > s1.length())
                    return -1;
                return 0;
            }

        });


    String descOrderedString = "";
    for (String item : items) {
        descOrderedString += item + " ";
    }

    System.out.println(descOrderedString);
```

where the method `print()` can be something like this:

```
public void print(List<String> list) {
    for(String s: list){
        System.out.println(s);
    } 
}
```

**Output:**

for `print(items)` is:

```
my
name
is
dhana
```

for the `System.out.println(descOrderedString)` is:

```
dhana name my is
```

Comment: ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException